# Equivalence class clarification

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

I'm slightly confused on the definition of an equivalence class. Suppose $R$ is a relation on $Z \times (Z - {0})$ by $(a,b)R(c,d)$ if and only if $ad = bc$. What would a single equivalence class from this look like?

$(-3, 2)$ is related to $(-3, 2)$, and $(-3,-3)R(-3,-3)$ - are these in the same equivalence class?

Comment: No, because $\langle -3,2\rangle$ is not related to $\langle -3,-3\rangle$: $(-3)(-3)\ne(2)(-3)$.

Comment: You ask "are these in the same equivalence class?". But you do not say what "these" are, so your question does not make sense. A sensible question might be "are $(-3,2)$ and $(-3,2)$ in the same equivalence?" Or "are $(-3,2)$ and $(-3,-3)$ in the same equivalence class?" Or any question of the form "are $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ in the same equivalence class?" where $a,b,c,d$ are replaced by specific numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relation you describe is the one used to define the set of rationals $\Bbb{Q}$. Namely, an equivalence class $[a,b]_R$ for this relation can be represented by the fraction $\frac{a}{b}$ and for every fraction $\frac{c}{d}=\frac{a}{b} \in \Bbb{Q}$, you have $(c,d)\in [a,b]_R$.

Comment: And to give a specific example of an equivalence class, the equivalence class $[(2,3)]_R$ of $(2,3)$ would be $$[(2,3)]_R=\{\ldots,(-8,-12),(-6,-9),(-4,-6),(-2,-3),(2,3),(4,6),(6,9),(8,12), \ldots \}$$

Comment: This cleared it up - thanks!